# What does 的 mean in 表示对某人某事的亲近和关心?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, preposition

In the following sentence which explains the usage of `～长～短` phrase:

> 中间嵌入两个相同的名词，表示**对某人某事的**亲近和关心。

I don't understand what the 的 here means. Does it refer to "of ~" but what should be after 的 is omitted here? So without any omission, it should be:

> 表示对某人某事**的东西**亲近和关心。

Or does it modify the noun after that (亲近和关心)? In that case, I don't understand then what is the object of 表示, since the whole phrase is now under a preposition (对).

Or am I missing something here and possibly neither is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示 (v) = to indicate /to show / to express

**对**某人某事 = **toward** some person or something

"对某人某事(的)" = "(of) toward some person or something"

的 functions as an adjectival suffix here. The whole phrase "对某人某事的" is now an adjectival phrase for the object "亲近和关心" (fondness and concern)

> [表示] [**对某人某事的**] [亲近和关心。]
>
> [to express ] [the fondness and concern] [**toward some person or something**]